# Como puedo Validar correo electrónico en un formulario para que no se vuelva a repetir al registrar otro?

Tags: php

```html
<?
$Usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
$Correo=$_POST['email'];
$Contraseña=$_POST['pass'];
$rpass=$_POST['pass2'];



$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","cbtis172");
mysql_select_db("shop");



if($Contraseña === $rpass)
{
 
$query="insert into usuario values('".$Usuario."','".$Correo."','".$Contraseña."')";
mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
{
$mensaje = "Exito al insertar";
echo "<script>";
echo "alert('$mensaje');";  
echo "window.location = 'index.html';";
echo "</script>"; 
}

 

} 
else
{
 echo "Introduce la contraseña";
}    
 mysql_close($connection);
?>
```

Comment: tienes que verificar la existencia de ese correo en tu base de datos. , luego si existe , no haces nada, si no existe continuas con tu algoritmo

Comment: Antes de realizar el INSERT, haces una consulta a la base de datos, tipo "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$Correo' LIMIT 1"; ya alli tienes el valor, si encuentra un resultado lanzas el alert de que ya existe el correo, de lo contrario lo dejas registrarse

Comment: No relacionado con la pregunta directamente: estás usando funciones `mysql_*` que están obsoletas y fueron eliminadas del estándar PHP, deberías considerar cambiarte a `mysli_*` o a `PDO`. Además, el código que compartes es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería usarse en entornos de producción. Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP.

Comment: Las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Lee [ask] y edita la pregunta con las recomendaciones que encontrarás allí, por ejemplo: añade una pequeña descripción de lo que hace el código, el resultado que esperas y el que obtienes. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Haz un select de ese email en tu base de datos y si te devuelve un resultado es que existe y tienes que mandar un mensaje al usuario de que el email existe y si no pues se crea el registro.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE email='".$Correo."'";
if(mysql_query($query)){
    echo "El email existe.";
}
else{
    $query="insert into usuario.....";
    mysql_query($query);
    echo "Registro realizado con éxito.";
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Es algo simple, realizas una consulta a tu base de datos a la tabla de los `usuarios`, para que valide si el correo existe, de ser asi que arroje algun error, de lo contrario que continue el flujo del sistema.

```
<?
    $Usuario=$_POST['usuario'];
    $Correo=$_POST['email'];
    $Contraseña=$_POST['pass'];
    $rpass=$_POST['pass2'];



    $connection=mysql_connect("localhost","root","cbtis172");
    mysql_select_db("shop");´

$comprueba = "select correo from usuarios where correo = '$Correo'";
$validar= mysqli_query($connection, $comprueba)

if(mysql_num_rows($validar) == 0){

    if($Contraseña === $rpass){

      $query="insert into usuario values('".$Usuario."','".$Correo."','".$Contraseña."')";
      mysql_query($query);
      if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){

         $mensaje = "Exito al insertar";
         echo "<script>";
         echo "alert('$mensaje');";  
         echo "window.location = 'index.html';";
         echo "</script>"; 
      }
    }   else {
        echo "Introduce la contraseña";
    }               
   mysql_close($connection);
}else{

echo "El correo ya existe";
}

?>
```